# Jquery elements not rebinding + HTMLDivElement unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

I am creating a dynamic refresh feature for div elements on my site that need to be dynamically refreshed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        function refreshDiv() {
            var refreshUrl =  window.location.pathname;

            $('.refreshable').each(function() {
                $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                    $(this).hide().load(refreshUrl + " " + this, "").fadeIn("slow");
                });
            });
        }

        $(document.body).on("click", ".login_button.submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var username = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : '/login',
                data : {username:username, password:password},

                success:function(response) {
                    if(response.status == 'success') {

                        $('#sb-site').animate({'opacity': '1'}, 300);
                        $('#login_form').toggle();
                        refreshDiv();

                    } else {
                        console.log('Something went wrong');
                    }
                },
                error:function(response) { 
                    console.log('Something went wrong');
                }
            });
        });

        $(document.body).on("click", ".logout_button", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : '/logout',

                success:function(response) {

                    if(response.status == 'success') {
                        refreshDiv();
                    } else {
                        console.log('Something went wrong');
                    }

                },
                error:function(response) { 
                    console.log('Something went wrong');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I have a few issues that have come up.

1) After logout is clicked, it calls the Laravel controller at /logout.  After that, it loads up the page with the refreshed content, but the jquery click events wont rebind, so I have to refresh in order to log in again after a logout.  The elements rebind fine after login happens, however.  I figured using .on() would fix this, but it has not.

2) Elements are duplicated because I am having trouble implementing 'this' into the refreshDiv function.  I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement]
```

This doesn't happen if I do

```
$(this).hide().load(refreshUrl + " .refreshable>*", "").fadeIn("slow");
```

but I need it to reload each specific targeted element individually, or it overlaps the content with matching classes.  I tried:

```
$(this).hide().load(refreshUrl + " " + this, "").fadeIn("slow");
```

My goal is to just be able to have a scalable solution to just add a .refresh class to a wrapper that needs to be dynamically refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell exactly what you want from `this` as shown in your call to `.load()`. The reason your error is showing up is because you are implicitly casting `this` to a string. The result is `"[object HTMLDivElement]"` which makes your call look like this

```
$(this).hide().load(refreshUrl + " " + "[object HTMLDivElement]", "").fadeIn("slow");
```

and that should clear up why the error occurs. What do you need from the div element in that spot?

In order to access the current div, just use `prop` or `attr` or native calls to get the information out from that point, such as `this.className` or `this.id` or `$(this).data('location')` etc.

However, as you have already started this chain off with `$(this)`, making the call to `.load` will already apply the loaded content at refreshUrl to the current `this` element.

So really all you need to do is

```
$(this).hide().load(refreshUrl,function(){
    $(this).fadeIn('slow'); // only fade in once content is loaded
});
```

Or perhaps you want the fade to occur while the data loads, in which case `$(this).hide().load(refreshUrl).fadeIn("slow");` would be used.

Comment: Using .attr just returns .refreshable, and I only need one .refreshable class targeted at a time.  The $(this) is referencing the currently selected div with that class; in this case '.refreshable'.  I see why the htmldivelement thing didn't work now.  Thanks.  I tried implementing your code, but it seems to throw an error saying Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.  Plus it seems to be breaking my X-CSRF somehow.  I'm not really sure where that's coming from.